# Git merge-commit is not being shown as merge in Git/SourceTree

Tags: git, merge

I merged two branches yesterday. During merging I accidentally stashed some changes, while resolving merge conflicts.

I just realized that now Git/SourceTree is now not showing the merge-commit as a merge in that it does not have a graphical link/line to the merged commit.

I am not sure how this came to be and if its was due to the stashing mentioned above or some other mistake on my behalf.

Since the merge I have put in some effort into fixing build errors, etc., so I would not want to restart.

So my question is: Is there some way to fix this?!

Comment: You could try this: Check out the commit, make a copy of all the files, reset back to before you did the merge, redo the merge without committing, copy back all the fixed files, add and commit.

Comment: What does the diff for that accidental commit look like?  To me it seems perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to apply that stash...somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your viewer is showing you the commit accurately, and does not show it as a merge commit, then it is indeed not a merge commit.

In reverse order (rather like Git):

> So my question is: Is there some way to fix this?!

Yes.  Save the desired post-merge result, by committing if necessary.  Save anything else necessary (e.g., make additional commits as desired).  We do this *because* commits are mostly-permanent, i.e., we'll be able to get them back.

Then, use `git reset --hard <hash>` to move the current branch name back to the point just before everything had gone wrong, and repeat the merge.  Use the saved result to set up the desired merge result, and commit it.  Continue copying additional commits if needed (using `git cherry-pick`).  See the example below (under the "recovering" section).

> I merged two branches yesterday. During merging I accidentally stashed some changes, while resolving merge conflicts.

This should be impossible—unless, that is, you'd marked all files as resolved.  To demonstrate, I set up a merge conflict and ran `git stash`:

```
$ git merge sidebr
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
[elf.24] T> git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git stash
file: needs merge
file: needs merge
file: unmerged (3b0f0fbe60a4e91d6bc2b714ecaf6b7626067fbb)
file: unmerged (94101158b0ecff92a135ff928f9497c9d8ac8c16)
file: unmerged (70f0a490221b56a23f0879634b84cb6b1f9166c5)
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
Cannot save the current index state
$
```

Here's the conflicted file, just for reference:

```
$ cat file
file for making a merge conflict
<<<<<<< HEAD
this is the second line
||||||| merged common ancestors
line 2
=======
line two
>>>>>>> sidebr
```

Let's mark it resolved (while leaving all the conflict markers in it) and stash and see if that destroys our merge state:

```
$ git add file
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   file

$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 33773a5 conflicting change on master
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Indeed, making the two stash commits and doing a `git reset` (which `git stash` does) *has* destroyed the merge state.  Applying and dropping the stash does not restore the merge state:

```
$ git stash apply
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git stash drop
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (187eaa6e372592f697ea7f0dc43056aadb8b7a18)
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

#### Recovering

Now, everything went wrong from the point of the uncommitted merge forward.  Let's get a quick look at what we have now (you can use your favorite viewer as long as it shows enough):

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 33773a5 (HEAD -> master) conflicting change on master
| * c46f563 (sidebr) conflicting-change-on-sidebr
|/  
* f23af46 mergebase
* d588ca0 initial
```

We just saw that we have not committed the "good" final merge result (it's not very good so let's put in a demonstration version), so we should commit that now:

```
$ cat << end > file
> file for making a merge conflict
> which is now resolved
> end
$ git add file
$ git commit -m merged-but-not-merged
[master ba3208a] merged-but-not-merged
 Date: Fri Jan 12 07:38:16 2018 -0800
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git show
commit ba3208a75c3f4132d32b2d258fc8d4f1582e5837 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Jan 12 07:38:16 2018 -0800

    merged-but-not-merged

diff --git a/file b/file
index 9410115..14e570a 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 file for making a merge conflict
-this is the second line
+which is now resolved
```

The hash ID with the resolved data is `ba3208a75c3f4132d32b2d258fc8d4f1582e5837`—the short version will suffice as well—and everything is clean:

```
# help from A DOG: All Decorate Oneline Graph
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* ba3208a (HEAD -> master) merged-but-not-merged
* 33773a5 conflicting change on master
| * c46f563 (sidebr) conflicting-change-on-sidebr
|/  
* f23af46 mergebase
* d588ca0 initial
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

We are now ready to use `git reset --hard`, which will *seem* to lose all our work, but in fact those commits are still in Git, held by their reflog entries (use `git reflog` to see them) and we've jotted down, or copied to another window, the key hash IDs:

```
$ git reset --hard 33773a5
HEAD is now at 33773a5 conflicting change on master
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 33773a5 (HEAD -> master) conflicting change on master
| * c46f563 (sidebr) conflicting-change-on-sidebr
|/  
* f23af46 mergebase
* d588ca0 initial
```

Now we are ready to re-do the merge, correctly this time:

```
$ git merge sidebr
Auto-merging file
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

The "good results" are in the commit whose ID we saved, so extract them.  You can use `git checkout <hash> -- .` as long as you are in the top level of your tree, and this command is easier to remember, though I will use `git read-tree --reset -u`, which also avoids the occasional thorny issue with files resolved by *deleting* them:

```
$ git read-tree --reset -u ba3208a  # or git checkout ba3208a -- .
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   file

$ git commit
```

At this point, your chosen editor comes up so that you can construct a better merge message than the default one, but I left the default in and exited the editor:

```
[master e097ef5] Merge branch 'sidebr'
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
*   e097ef5 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'sidebr'
|\  
| * c46f563 (sidebr) conflicting-change-on-sidebr
* | 33773a5 conflicting change on master
|/  
* f23af46 mergebase
* d588ca0 initial
$ cat file
file for making a merge conflict
which is now resolved
```

So we're done here, unless you have additional commits, in which case you can now use `git cherry-pick` to copy them into place after the new merge (in my case the new merge has the short hash ID `e097ef5` but yours will of course differ).

Comment: Well done. If ever step on myself like this, I know where to find the answer!

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much for this extensive demonstration. Saved me quite some time also. I especially like the mentioning of `git reflog`. I was unaware of this functionality. I should probably start using git more from the console.